# Как распарсить такую строку?

Tags: java

У меня есть строка такого типа

> Длительность: 02:18:19 Озвучка: оригинал Страна: Россия Жанры: драма военный отечественный В ролях: кто-то кто-то кто-то еще Режиссер: реж Описание: блабла

Каким образом я могу забрать информацию средствами Java? Чтобы было так:

> 02:18:19,,,,оригинал,,,,Россия,,,,Драма, Военный, Отечественный,,,,Кто-то, Кто-то, Кто-то еще,,,,реж,,,,блабла

Если сплитить по двоеточию и брать все четные элементы массива, то двоеточия есть в длительности и в описании могут быть

А если сплить по двоеточию с пробелом то... Вот, не могу никак додумать

Comment: Если имена полей одинаковы, то регэкспами.

Comment: Не разобрался как...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [регулярными выражениями](https://regex101.com/r/SjybvU/1):

```
String str = "Длительность: 02:18:19 Озвучка: оригинал Страна: Россия Жанры: драма военный отечественный В ролях: кто-то кто-то кто-то еще Режиссер: реж Описание: блабла";
String p = "Длительность: (.*) Озвучка: (.*) Страна: (.*) Жанры: (.*) В ролях: (.*) Режиссер: (.*) Описание: (.*)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(p);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    for (int i=1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
02:18:19
оригинал
Россия
драма военный отечественный
кто-то кто-то кто-то еще
реж
блабла
```